# Ramp-down scenario in jmeter (using normal thread )

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to  run my JMeter script with the below scenario design
Test scenario 50 min ramp up time  test duration 1 hour and 25 mins for ramp-down

My jmx contains the below elements (adding ramp-up 3000(50 mins)
Normal thread group (up to 500 users)
Login (once only controller)
runtime controller (1 hour + 50 mins ramp up)
Logout(once only controller)

Now my question is how can I achieve this scenario using a normal thread group as I am using runtime controller so I am not able to use ultimate or other thread groups .
Is there another thread group or idea to achieve it in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

Since [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) there is [Open Model Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Open_Model_Thread_Group) which allows you to more or less flexibly define ramp-down periods

[image]